# Datatable export multiple searched and selected rows

Tags: php, jquery, export-to-csv, datatables-1.10

i am not able to export multiple time searched and selected data to CSV.
i am fetching data from database which has more than 1000 records. 
so for example, if i select 2 rows on page one then i search for some other record and select that record and export but it is only exports searched record not the records from the page one.

```
$('#master tfoot th').each(function() {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
});

// DataTable

var master = $('#master').DataTable({
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy',
        'csv',
        'excel',
        'pdf',
        {
            extend: 'print',
            text: 'Print all (not just selected)',
            exportOptions: {
                modifier: {
                    selected: null
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    select: true
});


// Apply the search
master.columns().every(function() {
    var that = this;

    $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function() {
        if (that.search() !== this.value) {
            that
                .search(this.value)
                .draw();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is the data of the datatables inside the document or on the server-side processed.

Comment: @Jan i am calling data from database and displaying it through foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation when using processing on the server-side. In this case the datatable-object only knows the data of the current draw. This is the reason you are only able to export the visible/rendered content of the table.

If you want to export the data from all currently selected rows, you could listen for the `select.dt` and `deselect.dt` events of the datatable and store the row-data of the selection in an extra array from that you can create the csv-data for an export.

Further information and examples about the events can be found in the oficial doumentation:

- [select event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/select)
- [deselect event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/deselect)

Whenever the selection changes, an event will be dispatched. We can listen for this `select`-event, check if the selection is of type `row` and add the data to an array or object. Since we want to prevent duplicates, we should choose an unique key for the data (based on an id or some other data of the row).

Depending on how you have implemented your datatable and the processing, you have to watch for the `deselect`-event too. And maybe add some special handling of the pagination inside the datatable, so that rows on other pages are displayed as selected when you navigate to them again.

```
let selectedRows = {}; // holds all the data of selected rows

let table = $('#example').DataTable({ /* settings */ });
table.on('select', function(e, dt, type, indexes) {
  if ( type === 'row' ) {
    let data = table.rows( indexes ).data();
    for (let item of data) {
      let key = item[0] + '_' + item[2] + '_' + item[2]; // an unique key, for example built from: eventName, firstName and lastName
      if (!(key in selectedRows)) {
        selectedRows[key] = item;
      } 
    }
  }
});
// Todo: handle deselect and maybe pagination...
```

You can then export that data inside the browser with javascript.

```
let csvData = 'COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2,COLUMN_3, ..., COLUMN_N';
for (let row of selectedRows) {
  csvData = csvData + '\n'
   + '"' + row.column_1 + '",'
   + '"' + row.column_2 + '",'
   + '"' + row.column_3 + '",'
   /* ... */
   + '"' + row.column_N + '",';

// Create temporary download-element
let a = window.document.createElement('a');
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([csvData], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' }));
a.download = 'export.csv';
a.display = 'none';

// Append element to body and click it
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();

// Remove element from body
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

Note: If your data has strings that includes double quotes `"`, you have to escape them with an extra double quote `""`.

Comment: I was trying to do that only before this. i was getting all the selected rows but was not able to export that. so can you tell me how to export that data?

Comment: I've updated my answer with further information on how to listen and handle the select-event. This should point you in the right direction. The creation of the CSV can happen inside the browser/javascript with this. just iterate over the object with the selected rows.

Comment: i am getting all the selected data in javascript array.but i am not able to export that data.

Comment: I've added an example on how to export an array to csv (as download) with javascript.